# Duplicating an entry based on entry_id

Tags: php, channel-entries-api, api

I'm having a small issue creating a script that take in an entry_id, and based on that creates a new carbon copy entry with a new entry_id.

I've got this working, however as it stands now i'm forced to updated the $entry_data array everytime a new ee_channel_data field_id_# column is created.

```
ee()->load->library('api');
ee()->api->instantiate('channel_entries');
ee()->api->instantiate('channel_fields');

$entry_data = array(
    'title' =>  $get_channel_title_res['title'] . ' COPY',
    'url_title' =>  $get_channel_title_res['url_title'] . '_copy',
    'entry_date' => $get_channel_title_res['entry_date'],
    'edit_date' =>  $get_channel_title_res['edit_date'],
    'field_id_1' => $get_channel_data_res['field_id_1'],
    'field_id_2' => $get_channel_data_res['field_id_2'],
    'field_id_3' => $get_channel_data_res['field_id_3']
);

ee()->api_channel_fields->setup_entry_settings($channel_id, $entry_data);               

$success = ee()->api_channel_entries->save_entry($entry_data, $channel_id);
```

I would prefer not to have to specify the fields, but simply tell EE's API
Create a new entry, based on this old entry, and change it's title/url_title to appent _COPY.

I realize there's an addon for this, however that's not an option for me

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered an answer like this?

```
$entry_data = array();

// select all column names from your exp_channel_data table
$col_names = ee()->db->query('SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' AND `TABLE_NAME`='exp_channel_data')->result_array();

foreach ($col_names as $column_name) {
    // conditionals
    switch ($column_name) {

        // don't add an entry_id, 'cause auto insertion (giggity)
        case "entry_id":
            break;

        // title string append
        case "title":
            $entry_data[$column_name] = $get_channel_title_res[$column_name] . ' COPY';
            break;

        // url_title string append
        case "url_title";
            $entry_data[$column_name] = $get_channel_title_res[$column_name] . '_copy';

        // add everything else
        default:
            if (isset($get_channel_title_res[$column_name])) {
                $entry_data[$column_name] = $get_channel_title_res[$column_name];
            }
    }
}

// continue along your merry way with your api wackery
```

**Edit**

There isn't a built in function to do what you're asking.

OK, what about something even simpler? Assuming you have the `entry_id` you want to clone...

```
// get old data
$entry_data = ee()->db->select()
                      ->from('exp_channel_data')
                      ->where('entry_id', $entry_id)
                      ->get()->result_array();

// fix our copy
$entry_data["entry_id"]   = "";
$entry_data["title"]     .= " COPY";
$entry_data["url_title"] .= "_copy";

// move along, nothing to see here
```

Adds a database call but looks nicer!

Comment: I have, this was plan-B. I was just hoping that there's a cleaner way to do this via API call like ee()->api_channel_entries->copy_from($thisentry);

Comment: There isn't that functionality built in to the EE channel entries api. Sorry.

Comment: and there is this https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-cloner

Comment: Yea, we try to stay away from addons, modules and extensions. I saw mx-cloner when researching how to duplicate entries. But that was not an option. Thanks though!